# Default value to drupal variable

Tags: forms, configuration

I have a piece of code that I want to have the default value be a variable, but I need to know how to set a default value if the variable is not set:

```
  $form['background_audio_height'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Subject'),
'#default_value' => variable_get('background_audio_upload_path'),
'#size' => 5,
'#maxlength' => 3,
'#required' => TRUE,
);
```

How can I set a default value if background_audio_upload_path is not set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a second variable to the [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) function, which is a default value.

example:

```
variable_get('background_audio_upload_path', 'path/to/foo.bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function my_module_menu() {
  $menu['my_form_page/%'] = array
  (
    'title' => 'My Form',
    'page callback' => 'my_form_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $menu;
}

function my_module_load_data($item_id) {
  return db_query('SELECT value1 FROM {some_table} WHERE item_id = :item_id', array(':item_id' => $item_id))->fetchObject();
}

function my_form_page($item_id) {
  $my_object = my_module_load_data($item_id);
  return drupal_get_form('my_form', $my_object);
}

function my_form($form, &$form_state, $my_object) {
  $form['element1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Item 1'),
    '#default_value' => $my_object->value1,
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing many operations with variables, consider using [Variable](http://drupal.org/project/variable) module.

Once setup, it will save your time a lot. One of the problem that it will fix for you is the default value of the variable which you will need to change only in one place, instead of going through all the code. It will also provide you a configuration form for your variables for free.